# Delivering json content to different browser types using restlet

Tags: java, ajax, json, cross-browser, restlet

We have developed a RESTful webservice using the [restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) framework. The service is called by ajax requests using Prototype and/or Scriptaculous (I'm not familiar with those libraries, so excuse if any of these mentioned are not accurate).

Everything seems to work for most of the popular browsers, i.e. Opera, Firefox, Safari all work fine. Only Internet Explorer (6 and 7) does not get data from the call.

Our suspicion is that the returned content type "application/json" does not work in IE. We deliver the json content in "UTF-8", so that may also be a problem.

Any hints and suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 6 8 handles JSON responses with "application/json" without any problems. You need to trace server's response using such tool as [HttpWatch Pro](http://www.httpwatch.com/) for example.

Comment: Done that, the servers response is as expected.

Comment: Are there any error messages in IE (error sign in buttom left corner)?